# What are Goldbach conjecture for other algebra structures, matrix, polynomial, algebraic number, etc?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, goldbachs-conjecture

All:

what are Goldbach conjectures for other algebraic structures, such as: matrix, polynomial ring, algebraic number, vectors, and other algebraic structures ?

In other word, for other algebraic structures, such as: matrix, polynomial ring, algebraic number, vectors, etc.

What does "even" element mean ? 
What does "prime" element mean ?

Can every "even" element for those algebraic structures be partitioned into two "prime" elements ?

Has Goldbach Conjecture been proved for other algebraic structures ?

Comment: A very interesting and intelligent question. I can't believe that it did not attract more upvotes.

Answer (score 8):

Paul Pollack proved in this [paper](http://pollack.uga.edu/gcpoly.pdf)<sup>1</sup> the following version of Goldbach for polynomial rings:

**Theorem (Pollack)**: let $R$ be a Noetherian ring with infinitely many maximal ideals. Then every polynomial in $R[x]$ of degree $n\ge 1$ can be written as the sum of two irreducible polynomials of degree $n$.

For $R=\mathbb{Z}$ this has been proved by David Hayes in $1965$.

<sup>1</sup>P. Pollack: *On Polynomial Rings with a Goldbach Property* [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.118.01.071), [author's website](http://pollack.uga.edu/gcpoly.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180109074322/http://pollack.uga.edu/gcpoly.pdf)).